# Android pagerAdapter

Tags: android, fragmentpageradapter, android-pageradapter

I followed [this link](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-user-interface-design-horizontal-view-paging/)
to make a story app on Android but the problem is that the app is crashing after swiping 3 or 4 views (I am putting 5 pages to test but the story contains 13 pages).
 The views are not being moved from memory when they aren't displayed knowing that the destroyItem() method in the pagerAdapter Class is overriden.
 Please I need help. Thanks

Comment: Please post the code of your `PagerAdapter` and the stacktrace of the crash.